# convert 13 digit time code to date and time stamp using moment js and get the difference between them

Tags: node.js, datetime, momentjs

I have start time and end time as follows

```
var starttime=1631108701000
var endtime=1631116762000
var sessionstart=moment.unix(startTime);
var sessionend=moment.unix(endTime);
var ms = moment(sessionend,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(sessionstart,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var timeelapsed = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
```

goal is to display the starttime and endtime with proper date time stamp and disply the difference between then like 2hours16minutes53seconds or 02:16:53.The above code returns faulty data. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
var sessionstart= moment.unix(startTime/1000).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var sessionend= moment.unix(endTime/1000).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var ms = moment(sessionend,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(sessionstart,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var timeelapsed = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
```

By default moment.unix() expects in seconds so we need to divide by 1000 and format as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at this approach. First convert unix epoch milliseconds to seconds. Then use moment's `diff` function to calculate the respective units. Notice that I am adding corresponding units after each diff to get the accurate difference.

```js
const startTime = "1631108701000";
const endTime = "1631116762000";

// Converting epoch milliseconds to seconds
const startUnixTime = moment.unix(startTime / 1000);
const endUnixTime = moment.unix(endTime / 1000);

// hour difference
const hourDiff = endUnixTime.diff(startUnixTime, "hours");
startUnixTime.add(hourDiff, "hours");

// minute difference
const minDiff = endUnixTime.diff(startUnixTime, "minutes");
startUnixTime.add(minDiff, "minutes");

// second difference
const secDiff = endUnixTime.diff(startUnixTime, "seconds");

// Actual Input dates
const startDate = moment(startUnixTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
const endDate = moment(endUnixTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
console.log("Input start date", startDate);
console.log("Input end date", endDate);

// Difference in hours, minutes, seconds
console.log(hourDiff, minDiff, secDiff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```